# What is " No MediaQuery widget ancestor found" for rawscrollbar

Tags: flutter, media-queries

[I have recently started to learn flutter, can anyone explain me with that error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8l4h.png)

Comment: Include you code. Have you wrapped your widget with MaterialApp?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you need to wrap the Rawscrollbar widget you have shown in a material app widget. So just wrap your content in a material app widget  and wrap your roll scrollbar with a scaffold like so:

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    primaryColor: Colors.blueGrey
  ),
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('MaterialApp Theme'),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Check to see where materialapp is called e.g. within and stateless widget then make sure that your code is within the

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
```